# Add a custom format in Rails (that will work with respond_to)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, markdown

I have `map.resources :posts` and I want to be able to serve post bodies in markdown format. So I set up my `respond_to` block:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.markdown {
    render :text => @post.body.to_s
  }
end
```

But when I try to access `/posts/1234.markdown`, I get this error:

```
NameError (uninitialized constant Mime::MARKDOWN):
  app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:96:in `show'
  app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:79:in `show'
```

How do I add markdown as an acceptable format? Where can I see the list of acceptable formats?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2006/12/19/using-custom-mime-types

```
# add in config/initializers/mime_types.rb
Mime::Type.register "text/markdown", :markdown
```

Comment: Probably `config/initializers/mime_types.rb` might be the appropriate place for registering a new MIME type.

Comment: the link has been removed

Comment: The link is actually broken. You can find the article at http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2006/12/18/using-custom-mime-types/

Comment: @HarishShetty 's comment is an essential part of this answer. Please update your answer -- current docs suggest `config/initializers/mime_types.rb` -- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#restful-downloads

Answer (score 1):

```
Mime::Types.register
```