# 406 Not acceptable after format.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Weird “406 not acceptable” error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414446/weird-406-not-acceptable-error)

I receive a "406 Not acceptable" error after doing a respond_to with a format.js. This is the link:

```
    <%= link_to I18n.t(:alert_dismiss), :controller => 'alerts', :action => 'dismiss', :id => @alert, :remote => :true %>
```

This is the dismiss action from the alerts controller:

```
  # Sets alert dismiss status to true
  def dismiss
    # Get alert data
    @alert = Alert.find(params[:id])

    # Update status
    @alert.update_attribute(:dismiss, true)
    @alert.save!

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end

  end
```

And this is dismiss.js.erb:

```
$('.systemalert').empty();
```

Any idea what's wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `:true` to `true`

Also remove `save!` as `update_attribute` does that.

Comment: Changing true made no difference unfortunately.

Comment: Have you tried tidying up your route because apart from the `:true`, the request looks okay. In routes, try `match 'alerts/dismiss/:id' => 'alerts#dismis', :as => 'dismiss_alert', :via => :get`. Then you can use `dismiss_alert_path(@alert)` in your `link_to`

Answer (score 0):

Instead!!
This worked for me:

```
  render "users/invitations/createRequestInvite.js"
```