# RestKit and gzipped json

Tags: ios, http-headers, gzip, restkit, restkit-0.20

I have a question about RestKit framework.

I downloaded the restkit framework [from here](http://restkit.org/) and I can try to use RK with my URL example.
My question is: Can Restkit loading gzipped json?
I found this question [Restkit loading gzipped json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9720931/restkit-loading-gzipped-json)

but I not understood how can I set 
`[[RKClient sharedClient] setValue:@"gzip, deflate" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"]` (in my code this code line not work, not exist the methods)

How RestKit load the result of a request that use gzip, deflate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All that line is trying to do is set a header to be sent to the server. Latest SDK would be:

```
[[manager HTTPClient] setDefaultHeader:@"Accept-Encoding" value:@"gzip, deflate"]
```

Where `manager` is your `RKObjectManager` instance.