# 406 not acceptable error on mobile agents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, http-status-code-406

I am using angular application to run the application which uses ruby on rails backend apis. Our application works correctly on web desktop in different browsers but for mobile devices, I am getting 406 not acceptable errors for the same apis. Not getting a way to understand where is the problem in frontend code side or in backend api side.

Just to add the OPTIONS request is sent first on which I am getting this error.

Comment: have a look : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414446/weird-406-not-acceptable-error

Comment: can you show us some of code like controller's method where you were sending back json

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14251851/what-is-406-not-acceptable-response-in-http

Comment: @safinchacko my request headers are same in web and in mobile the difference is the mobile agent.

Answer (score 0):

Your backend service is saying that the response type it is returning is not provided in the Accept HTTP header in your Client request.

Ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields

Find out the response (content type) returned by Service.
Provide this (content type) in your request Accept header.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_status_code -> 406

[What is "406-Not Acceptable Response" in HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14251851/what-is-406-not-acceptable-response-in-http)

Comment: request headers are same which works in web but not in mobile. To test in mobile i just use the browser mobile view and i can see the 406 error